# Draw Canvas over eyes using the FaceDetectionListener

Tags: android, face-detection

I'm playing around with the `FaceDetectionListener`, my purpose is to draw a circle around the eyes. I have `SurfaceView` object named `preview` and a `SurfaceHolder` object named `previewHolder`.

Everything works quite well, I can detect who many faces which are represented in my `SurfaceView` using the backcamera. I also want to draw some circle around the left and right eye. My `drawCanvas` method looks like this:

```
      private void drawCanvas(float x, float y) {
            Canvas canvas = previewHolder.lockCanvas();
            Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);

            paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            paint.setDither(true); 
            paint.setColor(0xFFFFFF00);
            paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
            paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
            paint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
            paint.setStrokeWidth(3);

            canvas.drawPoint(x, y, paint);
            previewHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
      }
```

This method is called from the `FaceDetectionListener`:

```
      @Override
      public void onFaceDetection(Face[] faces, Camera camera) {

       if (faces.length > 0) {
           tv.setText(String.valueOf(faces.length) + " Face(s) Detected");

           for(Face f : faces) {

               int leftEyeXCoordinate =  f.leftEye.x;
               int leftEyeYCoordinate = f.leftEye.y;
               drawCanvas(leftEyeXCoordinate, leftEyeYCoordinate);

               int rightEyeXCoordinate = f.rightEye.x;
               int rightEyeYCoordinate = f.rightEye.y;
               drawCanvas(rightEyeXCoordinate, rightEyeYCoordinate);
           }
       }
       else
           tv.setText("No Faces Detected!");
      }};
```

I keep getting an NullPointerException at the line   `int leftEyeXCoordinate =  f.leftEye.x;`

Can I draw points, rects and other stuff while the camera is moving around? Or do I have to capture the picture first?

So my question is: Have anybody accomplished this before and want to tell me how I could do so?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, I have seen this problem too. Face object that is returned is android.hardware.Camera.Face instead of FaceDetector.Face and only the rect object has valid info in there. The bounds of the rect objects are in camera coordinate system. You will have to convert them to Views coordinate system. Its explained at this [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Face.html) under rect.